# VideoJS - multiple videos

Tags: html, video, video.js

I am needing to create a page that will include several videos 2-10. There are 2 options that I would like to consider. One, would be to just have a list of clickable links that would load into one player. The other would be to have all the videos in the their own players. The second option I can do by just having all the different video tags in my html, but this also allows all the videos to play at one time.

Of the 2 options above which one would be the easier method and where would I start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Video js  provides a feature where  it initializes itself  so no matter how many video tags are present in the single page all the players will be initialised  one by one.

Use following steps :

1. Add Videojs script tag ans CSS file in your head section.
2. Add class video-js in all the video tags  of your page and thats it.
3. Video js will be initialised on load in all the tags with class video-js

thanks